# Is there a way to run hook_form_alter after themes implementation?

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I'm using the [material_admin theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/material_admin), which has a `hook_form_alter()`  implementation.

I see that my module's [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.7.x) is executed before the theme hook. Both hooks are editing the same form property, so the change done in my code is always overridden.

In my [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Extension!module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/8.7.x) implementation I see only the modules that implement `hook_form_alter()`. The theme's implementation is not there.

How can I control its execution?

Comment: If your module is executes last it should not be overridden.

Answer (score 5):

I think you cannot have a module hook executed the same hook implemented by a theme. If we look at [the hook invoking code](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.7.6/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php#L835-836), we see that the theme hooks are invoked separately and after the module hooks.

The best bet would be to remove it from the theme and put it in a module, or trying with [`#after_build`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#after_build).

FormBuilder.php contains the following code.

```
$this->moduleHandler->alter($hooks, $form, $form_state, $form_id);
$this->themeManager->alter($hooks, $form, $form_state, $form_id);
```

Comment: Thanks that is helpful, I cannot remove it since material_admin is a contributed theme, and the project is maintained.Only with a patch which I'd like to avoid..

Comment: Maybe try #after_build form form API instead

Comment: Or you can create subtheme based on `material_admin` and implement your form_alter hook it will be executed after the material_admin form_alter hook.